# Empty/hide Flatlist ASAP when navigating between screens

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have two screens `History` and `Groups` with one flatlist each, and different data on each of them.
When I **first** load the screens, I have a loading icon displayed and then the flatlist appears when loaded. However when **navigating away and then back to one of the screen**, I see the following behavior:

- Old data displayed (~200ms)
- Loading icon displayed (~500ms)
- Updated flatlist displayed

Note: I am navigating from a screen to another using bottom Tab with react navigation and also a Drawer.

What I would like to achieve is to skip the old data and show the loading icon directly.

- Loading icon displayed (~500ms)
- Updated flatlist displayed

I have tried to add `setLoading(true)` in different places and `isFocused` but it did not help:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";
import {...} from "react-native";
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";


const Groups = ({ navigation }) => {
 
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  const { listEmptyComponent, loadFlatlist, dataOnDevice } = useContext(
    ConversionContext
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);    // Added this
    loadFlatlist("groups")
      .then()
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);      // Added this
    loadFlatlist("groups")
      .then()
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, [isFocused]);        // Added this

  return (
    <View>
      {loading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator/>
      ) : (
        <View>
          <StatusBar/>
          <FlatList
            data={dataOnDevice}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
              return (
                <RowItem
                  id={item.id}
                  key={item.id}
                  text={`ID: ${item.id} groupName: ${item.groupName}`}
                  onPress={() => {
                    navigation.pop();
                  }}
                />
              );
            }}
            ListEmptyComponent={() => listEmptyComponent()}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
              if (index !== null) {
                return index.toString();
              }
            }}
          />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default Groups;
```